# Not Getting form Data from View to Controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Not Getting form Data from View to Controller in MVC[image]

Comment: post the code. Not an image of the code.

Comment: you need to have input form fields to submit data. not labels

Comment: i had button submit in form but i checked form is submited , value of form collection is null

Answer (score 2):

Based on the posted code the issue is that there are no `<input>` fields in the form.

I might go so far as to assume that this is due to using the @Html.Label(...) instead of @Html.TextBox(...) or a different helper method that would render an input field into the form.

Whether you write out the html on your own or use the @Html helper methods, understanding what is going on is key.  It might be really helpful for you to look at the source and see what html is actually being rendered in order to better understand what the Razor is doing.

In order to submit a form and get the data back you generally want this pattern:

View:

```
...
<form action="/controller/ActionName" method="post">
    <input name="fieldName" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
...
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ActionName(string fieldName){
...
}
```

MVC will bind the fields based on the name attribute, but I highly encourage you to look into using model binding.